# RDP indirect connections

Tags: rdp

I currently have a need to RDP from my laptop to server A and then RDP from server A to server B.  So far, the only way I've found to go back to Server A is to log out of Server B.  Is there something I'm missing?  I'd really like to be able to switch between the two without closing the connection to B.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a tab at the top of the RDP screen. If you don't see it, try hovering your mouse up there.  You can slide that tab from side to side.  It has a minimize button on it.  If you're RDP'ed into one server and then into another from there, you will notice that you can slide that tab to the side, revealing another one underneath it for the other server.  You do not have to log out.

edited for clarity

Comment: +1 for "Slide the tab", been using RDP for years and never noticed ;)

Comment: Holy crap. How have I never seen this?

Comment: I deal with dozens of heavy rdp users at work. I'm quite certain at least 75% of them don't know about this. And that 75% includes the other sys-admins too.

Comment: That's a very well hidden feature.  Thank you Ryan.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the sliding tap & unpinning options in an existing connection... you can also skip the process of RDP'ing into one server to RDP to 2nd, if you implement the gateway service.  Basically, the "gateway" server will proxy the connection to the second server.  You will probably need to manually specify the gateway prior to connecting... (advanced tab -> click settings, and specify the "Use these RD Gateway server settings.")  In most instances, it is probably more of a headache to setup the gateway than it is simply to RDP twice.